# ImageMagick convert (PDF to JPG) returns white image with black stripes at the top

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I've encountered some issues in converting a multipage PDF files to JPG with ImageMagick.

The process returns a white page with black stripes at the top. It seems like the text has been 'compressed' and written at the very top of the page. I experience this behavior only with a given PDF file (the others work fine). I am running ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q16 on Windows. I also tried with ImageMagick-7.0.5 but I obtain the same result. I also tried using directly Ghostscript (9.21) and the output is the same. I think there must be something wrong with the PDF at this point.

[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/quijuuplkg3vswf/ObBboRc6Vzd7B1saQXS356ubjv6ATwBf4KbasBHaQ8g.pdf?dl=0) the pdf I am trying to convert to image and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xq7k7j9u75x45t0/ObBboRc6Vzd7B1saQXS356ubjv6ATwBf4KbasBHaQ8g-0.jpg?dl=0) is the result I obtain for the first page of the PDF. Subsequent ones are also like this.

Any clues on what's going on? Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: I would suggest you use `pdfimages` from the Poppler suite - I just extracted the 3 pages from your PDF without issues... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages

Comment: Issue is in the PDF document's internal stream. There should be warning emitted saying something like `**** Warning: stream Length incorrect`. Often this can be solved be re-authoring the PDF, and can be as simple as opening & re-exporting in a PDF reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. @emcconville: I tried to open and 'print to pdf' the file and it's now ok. Could you recommend a non-manual solution for dealing with this? I might need to scale the operation to multiple files

Comment: You'll need to identify how the files are generated, and fix the content-length  stream bug on that end. Or find a clever solution fail gracefully, and a secondary process to re-author the documents. -- Sorry

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried a ported version of Poppler in windows and it seems to work. It would be great if I could find a python wrapper for it (but it doesn't seem there are updated one unfortunately)

Comment: FWIW the current development HEAD in the Ghostscript Git repository renders the file as expected, despite the fact that it is broken. Note that there is no text in this file, its just an image, so the text isn't 'compressed' its the image which is garbled.

Comment: Perhaps it is hard to handle because it was created using a very old PDF-1.1 version. PDF versions are at 1.7. See https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/version. I tried ImageMagick 6.9.8.5 Q16 with GS 9.21 and it fails also.

Comment: @KenS Are you referring to the first version in this wepbage (http://git.ghostscript.com/)? And then I would need to build it from the source from scratch right?

Comment: I'm referring to the ghostpdl.git Git repository, yes. And yes, you would need to build from the source. A Visual Studio solution file is provided and is known to work with the Express (free for personal use) versions of Microsoft Visual Studio, though you have to allow VS to upgrade the solution because the files are deliberately kept at an old version for maximum compatibility.